# cancan for actions involving multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan for authorization.I have about 50 objects. There are actions involving 3 or 4 objects. 
when I setup the ability.rb should I have to list all 50 objects? 
What if a particular action involves updating more than 3 objects then on what object is the can method performed on.

Answer (score 0):

You should only authorize the objects that are actually involved with your app. In doing so, you're keeping it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

If more than 3 objects are involved in an action, then you need to work out what those are, because if you don't, then you might experience some problems in the future.

Can you list the actions that you've got please